# Powershell variable without automatic double quotes

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

Searched but can't find an answer to this (though there are very similar threads).

I have a variable `$var = 'string','string2,'string3'`

There is a cmdlet I'd like to pass this $var to

```
Set-DistributionGroup -ManagedBy $var
```

However, it ends up looking like this:

```
Set-DistributionGroup -ManagedBy "'string','string2','string3'"
```

And, I want:

```
Set-DistributionGroup -ManagedBy 'string','string2','string3'
```

Is this possible?  I wonder if it is, and likely is, a limitation with the Exchange PowerShell cmdlet Set-DistributionGroup.  ManagedBy is a MultiValuedProperty per docs.

Comment: What do you mean "it ends up looking like this"? Do you mean that's how `Set-DistributionGroup` interprets the command when you run it? Does an explicit cast to an array (or whatever type is appropriate) help?

Comment: I don't have this issue on server 2010. Seems to work just find as long as it can translate the alias property. Not familiar with the code you chose: `-param $var`... should it not be `Set-DistributionGroup -ManagedBy $var`?

Comment: Yes, the script runs Set-DistributionGroup and interpolates the variable by wrapping it in double quotes.  The variable doesn't contain double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The basic logic of passing a array of "users" to the `-ManagedBy` parameter works without any special intervention required. The only thing I can question is the line in you post

```
Set-DistributionGroup -param $var
```

Was that an attempt at generalizing the parameter switch name? Makes for some odd output regardless

```
[PS] >$list = "jim","tim"
[PS] >Set-DistributionGroup -param $list
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'jim tim'.
```

You should have just been able to do this:

```
[PS] >$list = "jim","tim"
[PS] >Set-DistributionGroup -ManagedBy $list
```

Assuming that `jim` and `tim` resolve to mailboxes. If they were aliases for example.

Comment: Yes, I generalized the parameter name and forgot to change it.  Question is edited.  Sounds like you are suggesting wrapping the users in double quotes instead of single.  I'll try this.

Comment: @jcarpio the quotes was a personal preference more than a suggestion. It should work either may as long as your array is populated with literals and not variables that need to be expanded.